# Toggle a nested SideBar with Javascript

Tags: javascript

[image: nested side bar]

I can get my side bar to take up the whole page when show/hide, but i wanted to have a nested side bar. so that when they show/hide it only opens in the div element, not over the whole page.
- Example would be if i had a main area in my home page, and when they click a button or hyper link, it hovers over the content on the side, but not the whole home page.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Toggle Sidebar</button>
  <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
  <p>Click on the hamburger menu/bar icon to open the sidebar, and push this content to the right.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: use `position:absolute` instead of `position:fixed`

Comment: ? what lol that didnt help

Comment: But you did put the `.sidebar` and the `#main` content inside that column? Or do you still have the markup inside the `<body>` as you posted it?

Comment: I have it like the example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am i right, you dont want that the Sidebar squeezes/shrinks the main area? So if Sidebar is shown it should hide/overflow the content?

Just comment out `//document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";`

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  //document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 15em;
  width: 15em;
  background-color: yellow;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Toggle Sidebar</button>
  <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
  <p>Click on the hamburger menu/bar icon to open the sidebar, and push this content to the right.</p>
  <div class="container">
  Test Content
  <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nativedigital thank you, but it still goves over the whole page
I need the hover over to be nested, ill add a picture to the main post

Comment: I've updated the code above, for example.

You need to tweak the CSS and HTML Elements accordingly.

Comment: thats almost it, when you add text to your <div class="container"> the popup show below the text in that box, it should overlap it...add this and youll see what im talking about

  <div class="container">
  Here is text<br/>
  Here is text<br/>
   <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
   <a href="#">About</a>
   <a href="#">Services</a>
   <a href="#">Clients</a>
   <a href="#">Contact</a>
 </div>
  </div>

Comment: I cant get it to work in test...
http://jsfiddle.net/36t8quck/